# Sorting rows into non-alphabetical customized order

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following `df`, where: `Name` displays the concept to pay for and `Code` the number of times `Name` must be repeated in order to optimize processes. Initially it looks like this:

```
Name    Code
Tax      1
Gas      2
Tax      1
Gas      2
Tax      1
Lunch    2
Tax      1
Car      2
```

`df = data.frame(Name = c('Tax', 'Gas', 'Tax', 'Gas', 'Tax', 'Lunch', 'Tax', 'Car'),
                Code = rep(c(1,2)))`

After repeating `Gas`, `Lunch` and `Car` twice, it looks like this:

```
Name    Code
Tax      1
Gas      2
Gas      2
Tax      1
Gas      2
Gas      2
Tax      1
Lunch    2
Lunch    2
Tax      1
Car      2
Car      2
```

`df = df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Code),]`

What I'd like to do is to reorder the rows to make my `df` look like this, where `df` is just sorted by `Code` in this manner `2`, `1`, `2` (each `Tax` and `Gas`, `Tax` and `Lunch`, `Tax` and `Car` are one group):

[image]

Is there a way to do so without any libraries? Since the final script will not be used just for me but also for r newbies at work.

I already tried with:
`df[order(factor(df$Code, levels = c(2,1,2))),]`
and also adding `row.names` as column to `match` like this: `df[order(df$Code, df$row.names),]` but it does not seem to work as expected.
Also tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549331/how-to-sort-a-data-frame-by-user-defined-e-g-non-alphabetic-order) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995285/custom-sorting-in-r) answers but could not succeed.

Comment: The sorting logic is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in `base R`

```
i1 <- with(df, ave(seq_len(nrow(df)), as.integer(gl(nrow(df), 3, 
         nrow(df))), FUN = function(i) c(i[c(2, 1, 3)])))
out <- df[i1,]
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#    Name Code
#1    Gas    2
#2    Tax    1
#3    Gas    2
#4    Gas    2
#5    Tax    1
#6    Gas    2
#7  Lunch    2
#8    Tax    1
#9  Lunch    2
#10   Car    2
#11   Tax    1
#12   Car    2
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% # initial dataset
   uncount(Code, .remove = FALSE) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   group_by(grp = gl(n(), 3, n())) %>%
   slice(c(2, 1, 3)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-rn, -grp)
```

Comment: I guess that I would call `tidyverse` a library.

Comment: Both solutions work fast and great. You did it! (as usual)... Thanks!

Comment: @Biostatician  Thanks, sorry, earlier I didn't read the question clearly and got busy

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly, assuming I understood the logic behind your sorting.

```
df = data.frame(Name = c('Tax', 'Gas', 'Tax', 'Gas', 'Tax', 'Lunch', 'Tax', 'Car'),
                Code = rep(c(1,2)))
df = df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Code),]
vect<-c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if ((i+1)%%3==0)
      vect<-c(vect,i,i-1,i+1)
}
df<-df[vect,] 
rownames(df)<-NULL
```